# Set QML Property from another QML

Tags: qt, qml, components, grid-layout

I have 2 qml files.

I want to set 2nd qml fromperty from the 1st qml file.

```
**first.qml**

var cmponent = Qt.createComponent("second.qml");
    var newObj = cmponent.createObject(swipeView);
    newObj.pageIndex = i;
    swipeView.insertItem(swipeView.currentIndex+i,newObj)
```

and insert into a SwipeView.

Where , '`pageIndex`'  is the integer property of 2nd qml.
In the second qml file I have a GridLayout with cells.
I need to display the cell content based on this dynamic `pageIndex` property

**second.qml**

declared the property.

```
 property int pageIndex: 0
    onPageIndexChanged:{
        console.log("onPageIndexChanged :" +pageIndex)
        home_grid.update()

    }
```

The `onPageIndexChanged` method is triggered but, I want to set the Grid cells based on the property value.

The issue is
While initialization of the component

```
var cmponent = Qt.createComponent("second.qml");
```

the cells are loaded into the GridLayout.

How can I relead/ solve this issue.

Comment: 1: Why do you create the objects with the JS-Functions? 2: Where is your GridLayout? What are the cells you want to display there? Can't you use a GridView with the index as a model?

Comment: 1. I want to create a views dynamically. based on the ListModel count. Each view have grid with maximum elements 6. Example : Model have 7 elements then, 6 elements display in firstView and the remaining 1 display on sendView with swipeView to switch these Views.  2. "GridLayout" is in another qml file (second.qml). Each cell/elements display on the grid from the values based on the Model.

Comment: It should be possible to use one `ListModel` in multiple views. So I would propose to use a `GridView` instead of the `GridLayout`. Then you can just use the 'magic' variable `index` in the delegates of this `GridView` for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

(I used my example for your fist question)
It should illustrate my comments.
Of course you can put the different views in different files. You just need to pass the same model to both, when creating the objects.

```
ListModel {
    id: lm
    ListElement { width: 40; height: 40 }
    [...]
    ListElement { width: 40; height: 40 }
}

SwipeView {
    width: 200
    height: 800
    clip: true
    currentIndex: 0

    Repeater {
        model: Math.ceil(lm.count / 6)
        delegate:            ListView {
            width: 200
            height: 800
            property int viewIndex: index
            model: DelegateModel {
                model: lm
                groups: DelegateModelGroup { name: 'filter' }
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    for (var i = viewIndex * 6; i < lm.count && i < (viewIndex * 6) + 6; i++) {
                        items.setGroups(i, 1, ['items', 'filter'])
                    }
                }

                filterOnGroup: 'filter'

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: 180
                    height: 30
                    border.width: 1
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

GridView {
    clip: true
    x: 300
    width: 600
    height: 600
    model: lm

    delegate: TestObj {
    }
}
```

Here is the Code for the delegate `TestObj`

```
Rectangle {
    width: model.width
    height: model.height
    property alias text: myText.text
    Text {
        id: myText
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: index
    }
}
```

Of course you could also write:

```
    delegate: TestObj {
        width: model.width; height: model.height; text: index
    }
```

which would minimize the dependencies of your second QML-File.

Comment: In the GridItem, I have to display lot of items and based on some conditions conditions.So I created a separate QML for Grid Item.

Comment: That is up to you. As you see, I did that as well, wit the TestObj.qml